# Android Dialog Fragment won't dismiss

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm writing a very simple dialog fragment that displays 3 choices and returns the choice back to a parent fragment. After a choice is made I want the dialog to dismiss itself. Below is the onCreateDialogMethod I wrote, with a call to CheckOutDialogFragment.this.dismiss(). I've also tried just dismiss() and a couple other methods. Any advice?

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activity = this.getActivity();
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    final String comment =  args.getString(CheckInOutFragment.COMMENT);
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    dialogAdapter = new CheckOutDialogAdapter(this.getActivity());
    final Intent data = new Intent();

    myAlertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(dialogAdapter, -1, new    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int selection){
            ActivityModel.CheckOutType type = dialogAdapter.getActivityTypeForIndex(selection);
            data.putExtra(CheckInOutFragment.COMMENT, comment);
            data.putExtra(CHOICE, type);
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            CheckOutDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
            //TODO: figure out why this won't dismiss
        }
    });

    return myAlertDialog.create();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my IDE needed a restart and my project wasn't building properly. Both CheckOutDialogFragment.this.dismiss() and dismiss() work.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
CheckOutDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
```

is should be just:

```
dismiss();
```